Clarification about probability of critical threshold for cliques in random graphs.
I am reading these notes about finding cliques in $\mathcal{G}(n, 1/2)$ random graphs. The key result is that with high probability has size $2(1\pm o(1)) \log_2(n)$ with high probability. In order to prove this they first show that for $k_0(n) = 2(1 + o(1)) \log_2(n)$:
$$\Pr[X_{k_0}(n) > 0] \to 1\text{ as } n\to \infty$$
Their derivation is as follows (under section "Upper Bound")

Now that we know the expected number of $k$-cliques in G, we can calculate the probability that $\mathbb{E}[X_k] > 0$. First observe that
$$\mathbb{E}[X_k] = {n \choose k} 2^{−{k \choose 2}} ≤ n^k 2^{-k(k−1)/2} = 2^{k\log(n)− k(k−1)/2} = 2^{(k/2)(2 \log(n)−k+1)}$$
This means that $E[X_{k_0(n)}]$ for $k_0(n) = 2\log(n) + 2$ is given by the following.
$$E[X_{k_0(n)}] \leq 2^{−(\log(n)+1)} = n^{−\Omega(1)}$$
Because $X_{k_0(n)}$ is an integer, we have by Markov’s inequality
$$\Pr[X_{k_0(n)} > 0] = 1 − \Pr[X_{k_0(n)} \leq 1] \geq 1 − n^{−\Omega(1)}$$

It seems like the larger you make $k_0(n)$ the smaller the expected value gets, which is fine. But what isn't fine is this smaller expected value seems to be used to conclude there is a high probability of a $k_0(n)$-clique existing. This seems rather odd to me. For instance, I would imagine at some point there should be a large enough $k'(n)$ where $\Pr[X_{k'(n)} > 0] \to 0$. Any guidance on rectifying my "sniff test" is appreciated.

I agree with you that they are wrong. The last inequality uses $\mbox{Pr}[X_{k_0(n)}\leq 1] \leq n^{-\Omega(1)}$, where they seem to have used Markov's inequality in the wrong way (it's actually $\mbox{Pr}[X_{k_0(n)}\geq 1] \leq n^{-\Omega(1)}$, from which we deduce nothing). It doesn't make sense either: the variable could very well be constant to 0, the expectancy would be small and $\mbox{Pr}[X\leq 1]$ would be 1.
Globally speaking, they inverted the two techniques in their proof: you can easily prove that $\mbox{Pr}[X_{k_1(n)}>0] \to 0$ using Markov's inequality, but you need to use the second moment method (or variance or Chebychev's inequality however you call it) to prove that $\mbox{Pr}[X_{k_0(n)}>0]\to 1$. To support my claim, here is this document from the same university but a different teacher that correctly sketches the proof, using the same notations (I have no idea what happened or why they are so well referenced on Google). The full proof is also found in Bollobas' book Modern Graph Theory, but he goes very fast on some inequalities in my opinion (at least I don't understand all of them).
